# Why operator() Function cannot be overloaded?

Tags: c++

I need to define a new function using the same parameters as another function which is already defined. Is it even possible? I tried doing that, but I'm getting an error:

> error: cannot be overloaded

Here is the code:

```cpp
#ifndef CORRELATOR_MEAN_SQUARE_DISPLACEMENT_HPP
#define CORRELATOR_MEAN_SQUARE_DISPLACEMENT_HPP

#include<halmd/numeric/blas/fixed_vector.hpp>
#include<typeinfo>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <memory>

namespace correlator {

class mean_square_displacement
{
public: 
    typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::multi_array<float, 2>> sample_type;
    typedef double result_type;  // fixed_vector<double, 3>
    
    result_type operator() (sample_type const& first, sample_type const& second) const
    { 
        double msd = 0;
        size_t N = first->size(); 
       
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                double dr = (*first)[i][j] - (*second)[i][j];
                msd += dr * dr;
                if (msd > 0)
                    std::cout << "msd::" <<  msd << std::endl;
            } 
        }
   
        return msd/N;
    } // msd operator ends here
    
    result_type operator() (sample_type const& first, sample_type const& second) const
    {
        return (std::cout << (*first)[0][0]<< "The first element :." << std::endl);
        
    }

};

} // namespace correlator

#endif /* ! CORRELATOR_MEAN_SQUARE_DISPLACEMENT_HPP */
```

What I'm trying to do is use parameters (first and second) from the first **operator** function and use them for different calculations in the second function. What am I doing wrong here?
I'm intentionally not posting all of the files. If someone wants, I can share them.

Comment: What would you want `correlator::mean_square_displacement{}(first, second)` to do?

Comment: How could the compiler distinguish one from the other? Consider different (descriptive) names for those functions or to also pass a tag argument.

Comment: No function can be "overload" this way.

Comment: if I have two functions `f(int)` in the same class, and I call `obj.f(3)`, how could the compiler possibly know which one I meant?  Overloading means using the same name, with different signatures, that is, _different_ argument types or counts.  Reusing identical functions means you are re-defining the same function.  Why do you have to call your "helper function" `operator()`, and not call it `operator_helper` instead, or any other name?

Comment: @Artyer first and second are the 2D arrays. I want to let's say subtract them.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to overload the same function name with the same signature (parameters and const/non-const). You should probably declare a new named function rather than overload the `()` operator.